# How to introduce internationalization of dictionaries in DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, internationalization

I have DB with many dictionaries. Till this moment it was written in english, but customer want to introduce internationalization on DB level (to support spanish and UK english). So users that will login to our system should see all text depending on his internationalization settings.

Most of dictionay tables are in form:

```
CREATE TABLE UserPermissionTypes (
Id [INT],  
Title NVARCHAR(100),  
Description NVARCHAR (500) )
```

At this moment I'm thinking about creating duplicated tables for each dictionary in form similiar to this one:

```
CREATE TABLE UserPermissionTypesTranslations (
UserPermissionTypesId [INT],
LanguageCodeId [INT]
Title NVARCHAR(100),  
Description NVARCHAR (500), )
```

I know that it is not perfect solution, so I want to know what is the best method to implement internationalization in tables?
Is there some standard way to do that inernationalization?

Comment: What is the difference between 'title' and 'description'? In which field would you put the string to be displayed? It may be that the translations table does not need the 'description' field as this might have the same value across all values of UserPermissionTypesId (would it not be better to call this field 'languageID')?

Comment: title is displayed on page and description is longer version displayed after hover on item: example: title: '1st grade Manager', description: 'User that manage 1-10 persons team'.

Comment: Then I think your proposed solution is the way to go - one would select the title and description on the basis of UserPermissionTypesID and LanguageCodeID.

Answer (score 1):

How about making extra table for translations and use it's ID instead of texts (modified after comments) :

```
    CREATE TABLE UserPermissions ( 
    Id [INT],   
    TitleTR [INT],   
    DescriptionTR [INT] ) 

    CREATE TABLE Translations(
    Id [INT],
    LanguageID [INT],
    Text NVARCHAR(500)
    )

select tr.Text as title, tr2.Text as description from UserPermissions
join Translations tr on tr.id=UserPermissions.titleTR and languageid=:LANG
join Translations tr2 on tr2.id=UserPermissions.descriptionTR and languageid=:LANG
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that fields have to be added to the table when a new language is needed.

Comment: It is good solution when you have fixed number of langages and only one field to translate. But there are 2 text fields in one row  in example table (Title, description). And I suppouse that my customer doesn't want to support only 2 languages. Adding new language could be difficult in this solution.